# GNU Make dynamically created variable name

Tags: gnu-make, dynamic-variables

This is my make recipe, I'm passing nonle value *, although bamboo_nonle_password variable is having password, still function is failing

```
validatevar.%: $(if $(IS_BAMBOO),)
        @echo "\n################################################################################"
        @echo ">>> validatevar"
        @echo ">>> Start: Validate bamboo variables "
ifndef bamboo_$*_password
        @echo "Bamboo variable bamboo_$*_password is empty"
        exit 1
endif
ifndef bamboo_$*_server
        @echo "Bamboo variable bamboo_$*_server is empty"
        exit 1
endif
        @echo "<<< Done: validatevar"
        @echo "################################################################################\n\n"
```

Comment: why is this extra comma here, `validatevar.%: $(if $(IS_BAMBOO),)` ? perhaps you can have 1 or 0, so that you can do like `IS_BAMBOO=1` like that.

Comment: yeah, that is also possible, anyhow it still works, I will change that in my code. but the real problem is in the generating variable name dynamically i.e generating bamboo_$*_password variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You crazy person :)

*Make* will expand the recipe just before it wants to execute it.
At this point *make* knows what the `%` corresponds to,
and so can ensure `$*` is set appropriately.
Unfortunately, the `ifndef`…`endif` pair is evaluated as the makefile is read,
not as the recipe is expanded.

This suggests the answer:
use macros.
Maybe `$(origin …)` or `$(flavor …)` in something like

```
validatevar.%:
    @echo 
    $(if $(filter undefined,$(origin bamboo_$*_password)),@echo "Bamboo variable bamboo_$*_password is undefined")
    $(if $(filter undefined,$(origin bamboo_$*_password)),exit 1)
```

Naturally you can tidy this up a bit.
Maybe:

```
die-if-undefined = $(if $(filter undefined,$(origin $1)),$(error "$1" is undefined))

validatevar.%:
    $(call die-if-undefined,bamboo_$*_password)
    $(call die-if-undefined,bamboo_$*_server)
    @echo 
    @echo
```

Two things to note:

1. The *whole* of the recipe is expanded in one go, *before* any of the lines are executed.
   The upshot of this is that it doesn't matter where you expand the `$(error)` assertions.
   I have put them at the top.
2. `ifndef` also detects empty variables, as well as undefined ones. You may wish to adjust `die-if-undefined` to take account of this (and rename it to `die-if-empty`).

(This would all be a lot easier if *make* would only take a `--error-undefined-variables` parameter,
just to match the existing `--warn-undefined-variables` parameter.)